# PerformanceCounter - Custom counters file view is out of memory

Tags: c#, .net, exception, performancecounter

While doing some load testing on our .Net Win32 application, I ran into some exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Custom counters file view is out of memory.
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter.CalculateMemory(Int32 oldOffset, Int32 totalSize, Int32& alignmentAdjustment)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter.CreateInstance(CategoryEntry* categoryPointer, Int32 instanceNameHashCode, String instanceName, PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime lifetime)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter.GetCounter(String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean enableReuse, PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime lifetime)
   at System.Diagnostics.SharedPerformanceCounter..ctor(String catName, String counterName, String instanceName, PerformanceCounterInstanceLifetime lifetime)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)
```

It happens when running this line:

```
new PerformanceCounter("CategoryName", "CounterName", "InstanceName", false);
```

I'm not very familiar with the performance counter, by seeing this message, I understand they are stored in some file, but is this the responsability of the developer to clear this file? If yes how? If no, what should I do?

I've 5 instance of this application running on the same machine.

Comment: Isn't this what you expect when you do a "load test"?  A counter is backed by a memory-mapped file to store the counter data.  That file has a preset limit, 32768 bytes by default.  Create way too many counters and you're out of space.  You can change the limit by hacking the registry.  Just don't.

Answer (score 0):

Performance Counters Implement IDisposable, so you can use

Directly:

```
 perfCounter.Close();
 perfCounter.Dispose();
```

Indirectly:

```
using(PerformanceCounter perfCounter=new PerformanceCounter())
{
   //Your Code.
}
```

to clear its resources.

Also you can allocate more memory to the performance counter using the registry. See this post in the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx

*Performance counter categories installed with the .NET Framework 2.0 use separate shared memory, with each performance counter category having its own memory. You can specify the size of separate shared memory by creating a DWORD named FileMappingSize in the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\\Performance. The FileMappingSize value is set to the shared memory size of the category. The default size is 131072 decimal. If the FileMappingSize value is not present, the fileMappingSize attribute value for the performanceCounters element specified in the Machine.config file is used, causing additional overhead for configuration file processing. You can realize a performance improvement for application startup by setting the file mapping size in the registry. For more information about the file mapping size, see  Element.*

Comment: Ok, but in my case I create the performance counter on startup, and I close them when closing the application, in the middle I've several call increasing those counter

Comment: Exactly two options: Dispose perfcounter whenever you run out of memory and create another and/or increase the memory allocated to your counter so you don't get the exception

Comment: Isn't there a way to increase the memory without going through the modification of the registry? I mean we cannot be sure that someone else will not modify this number, no?

Comment: There used to be a function call to increase memory allocation but it is now Obsolete. What this is saying is even if *you* don't put in a registry entry, I could later. Basically *someone else* can always modify that number

Comment: Well ok, anyway, I checked with people here, we can't add some registry values since it should be possible to drag&drop some files. Isn't there a way to increase this memory application wide?